# Unable to derive Diffie Hellman shared secret with OpenSSL in C++

Tags: c++, openssl, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to familiarise myself with the OpenSSL Diffie Hellman features and, in doing so, I've tried to create a simple programme which will generate two sets of Diffie Hellman private and public keys and then derive the shared secret. I have followed the Diffie Hellman tutorial on the OpenSSL wiki and I am able to generate the keys, however I am unable to derive the shared secret. My C++ (Linux) code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    EVP_PKEY* params;

    EVP_PKEY_CTX *kctx1, *kctx2, *dctx1, *dctx2;

    unsigned char *skey1, *skey2;
    size_t skeylen1, skeylen2;
    EVP_PKEY *dh_1, *dh_2;
    BIO* bio_out = NULL;
    int result = 0;
    ENGINE* eng;

    BIO* fp = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

    // Initalise Diffie Hellman PKEY for client 1
    if(NULL == (dh_1 = EVP_PKEY_new())) {
        std::cout << "error 1" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initalise Diffie Hellman PKEY for client 2
    if(NULL == (dh_2 = EVP_PKEY_new())) {
        std::cout << "error 2" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initalise Diffie Hellman parameter PKEY
    if(NULL == (params = EVP_PKEY_new())) {
        std::cout << "error 3" << std::endl;
    }

    // Set Diffie Hellman paramerers
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_set1_DH(params, DH_get_2048_256())) {
        std::cout << "error 4" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initalise client 1 PKEY Context
    if(!(kctx1 = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL))) {
        std::cout << "error 5" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initalise client 2 PKEY Context
    if(!(kctx2 = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL))) {
        std::cout << "error 6" << std::endl;
    }

    if(!kctx1) {
        std::cout << "error 7" << std::endl;
    }

    if(!kctx2) {
        std::cout << "error 8" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initalise both contexts key generators
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(kctx1)) {
        std::cout << "error 9" << std::endl;
    }

    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(kctx2)) {
        std::cout << "error 10" << std::endl;
    }

    // Generate DH public and private keys for client 1
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen(kctx1, &dh_1)) {
        std::cout << "error 11" << std::endl;
    }

    // Generate DH public and private keys for client 2
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen(kctx2, &dh_2)) {
        std::cout << "error 12" << std::endl;
    }

    // EVP_PKEY_print_public(fp, dh_1, 3, NULL);

    // EVP_PKEY_print_public(fp, dh_2, 3, NULL);

    // Create key derivation context
    if(NULL == (dctx1 = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(dh_1, NULL))) {
        std::cout << "error 13" << std::endl;
    }

    if(!dctx1) {
        std::cout << "error 14" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initalise first key derivation context
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_init(dctx1)) {
        std::cout << "error 15" << std::endl;
    }

    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_check(dctx1)) {
        std::cout << "error 16" << std::endl;
    }

    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_param_check(dctx1)) {
        std::cout << "error 17" << std::endl;
    }

    // Set first key derivation context peer key to the second DH PKEY
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(dctx1, dh_2)) {
        std::cout << "error 18" << std::endl;
    }

    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_public_check(dctx1)) {
        std::cout << "error 19" << std::endl;
    }

    /* Determine buffer length */
    if(EVP_PKEY_derive(dctx1, NULL, &skeylen1) <= 0) {
    }

    // Assign memory for shared key variable
    skey1 = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(skeylen1);

    if(result = EVP_PKEY_derive(dctx1, skey1, &skeylen1) <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << skey1 << std::endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < skeylen1; i++) {
            std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)skey1[i];
        }
    }

    ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

My main concerns are:

1. What do I need to do to derive the shared secret?
2. Do I need a new context for each key pair and key derivation?

Thanks!

## EDIT:

I get the following errors and no shared key:

```
140690271102784:error:05079079:Diffie-Hellman routines:DH_check_ex:unable to check generator:../crypto/dh/dh_check.c:92:

140690271102784:error:05079076:Diffie-Hellman routines:DH_check_ex:check p not safe prime:../crypto/dh/dh_check.c:96:

140690271102784:error:0507B07B:Diffie-Hellman routines:DH_check_pub_key_ex:check pubkey too large:../crypto/dh/dh_check.c:190:

140690271102784:error:0507B07A:Diffie-Hellman routines:DH_check_pub_key_ex:check pubkey invalid:../crypto/dh/dh_check.c:192:
```

when I use

```
    if(NULL == (dctx1 = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(dh_1, NULL))) {
        std::cout << "error 13" << std::endl;
    }
```

and I get the following errors

```
error 16
error 19

Key: �ȭ��U

c0c8add7c4550000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

139939742943040:error:060BA096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_check:operation not supported for this keytype:../crypto/evp/pmeth_gn.c:188:
139939742943040:error:0507C07D:Diffie-Hellman routines:dh_pkey_public_check:missing pubkey:../crypto/dh/dh_ameth.c:517:
139939742943040:error:05066064:Diffie-Hellman routines:compute_key:no private value:../crypto/dh/dh_key.c:183:
1
```

when I change "EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(dh_1, NULL)" to "EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL)", like so:

```
    if(NULL == (dctx1 = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL))) {
        std::cout << "error 13" << std::endl;
    }
```

The difference between these two variables is that "dh_1" stores a DH keypair, whereas "params" contains the DH parameters. It appears that the derivation context initalises to some extent with the latter, though it does not have a private and public key associated with it.

Comment: You say you are unable to derive the shared secret. What happens when you try? Do you get some kind of error message when you call `ERR_print_errors_fp`? If so what is it? How far does the process get before you run into trouble?

Comment: Hi @MattCaswell, I've updated my post to answer your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the version of the code that you posted I got slightly different errors to you. I get the following output from your code (linked against OpenSSL 1.1.1):

```
error 16
error 17
140673674348352:error:060BA096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_check:operation not supported for this keytype:crypto/evp/pmeth_gn.c:187:
140673674348352:error:05079076:Diffie-Hellman routines:DH_check_ex:check p not safe prime:crypto/dh/dh_check.c:93:
0
```

The first "error 16" output is simply because OpenSSL does not currently support the `EVP_PKEY_check()` call for Diffie-Hellman keys. So this can be safely ignored.

The second "error 17" output (which is associated with the "check p not safe prime" error in the error queue) is more of an issue. This is because Diffie-Hellman keys come in two different varieties. By default OpenSSL uses PKCS#3 Diffie-Hellman keys. However it also supports X9.42 Diffie-Hellman keys. The function `DH_get_2048_256()` gives you a built-in set of parameters for X9.42 keys. However the function `EVP_PKEY_set1_DH()` expects the provided DH object to be a PKCS#3 key.

This actually looks like a bug in OpenSSL to me (`EVP_PKEY_set1_DH()` should really detect what type of key it is and do the right thing), so I have raised the following OpenSSL issue for this:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/10592

You can work around this by replacing the `EVP_PKEY_set1_DH()` call with one to `EVP_PKEY_assign()` instead and specify the type as `EVP_PKEY_DHX` as follows:

```
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_assign(params, EVP_PKEY_DHX, DH_get_2048_256())) {
        std::cout << "error 4" << std::endl;
    }
```

Alternatively you might just use PKCS#3 parameters instead.

Finally, the reason you get no shared secret derived is because you are only printing it if the `EVP_PKEY_derive()` call fails! It is actually succeeding!

I made the following changes to your code and it works for me:

```
--- derive.cpp  2019-12-09 11:11:15.493349734 +0000
+++ derive-new.cpp  2019-12-09 11:14:59.348715074 +0000
@@ -37,7 +37,7 @@
     }

     // Set Diffie Hellman paramerers
-    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_set1_DH(params, DH_get_2048_256())) {
+    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_assign(params, EVP_PKEY_DHX, DH_get_2048_256())) {
         std::cout << "error 4" << std::endl;
     }

@@ -96,9 +96,11 @@
         std::cout << "error 15" << std::endl;
     }

+#if 0
     if(1 != EVP_PKEY_check(dctx1)) {
         std::cout << "error 16" << std::endl;
     }
+#endif

     if(1 != EVP_PKEY_param_check(dctx1)) {
         std::cout << "error 17" << std::endl;
@@ -120,7 +122,7 @@
     // Assign memory for shared key variable
     skey1 = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(skeylen1);

-    if(result = EVP_PKEY_derive(dctx1, skey1, &skeylen1) <= 0) {
+    if((result = EVP_PKEY_derive(dctx1, skey1, &skeylen1)) > 0) {
         std::cout << "Key: " << skey1 << std::endl;

         for(int i = 0; i < skeylen1; i++) {
```

Comment: Amazing, this solved my problem, thanks for the help! By the way, how did you find this out: "However the function EVP_PKEY_set1_DH() expects the provided DH object to be a PKCS#3 key."

Comment: I'm an OpenSSL dev ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Above is Eliptic Curve Diffie and Hellman. A working example with OpenSSL 3 (none eliptic curve)

https://gist.github.com/digitalhuman/2a2b85d61672e4bf83596d41351723ba